# sql delete statement android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Below is the delete statement and dialog alert

```
private void deleteRecord() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this item?");

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("users.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

                    String sql = "DELETE FROM CART WHERE CODE = " + id + ";";

                    db.execSQL(sql);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });


    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Debugging error ;

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Code": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM CART WHERE CODE = Product Code:p1120;

someone help me pls ?

Comment: Try this, DELETE FROM CART WHERE CODE ='" + id + "'";? I have added (') single quote before and after **id**.

Comment: The value of `id` is not what is required.

Comment: @Raghavendra u r right . thanks

Comment: @Raghavendra how if add another clause ? 
WHERE CODE ='" + id + "' + USER = '" + uname + "'";
not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
"WHERE CODE ='" + id + "' AND USER ='" + uname + "'";
```